# Why MDL drawer (navigation) icon is a square? Font missing?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, material-design-lite

I started working on a new Rails 4 project to learn some MDL. Now I am facing this issue (see image).

[image: font-missing?]

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">RubyStore</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">RubyStore</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">

  </main>
</div>
```

As you can see on the left side instead of a drawer icon I get this little weird square (let's just call it a square for simplicity...). What is weird though is that as you can see in the developer's tools the square is actually there.

```
<i class="material-icons"></i>
```

Here. See? What could be the reason? I am using newest MDL (downloaded) with MDL customization (downloaded). Ruby 2.3.0, Rails 4.2.5 and ERB as my templating.

I added both files (.css and .js) to `/app/assets/` and the respective folder. Both style and behavior works. I can click on the square and the drawer with slide out perfectly fine.

EDIT: Alright. I inspected the actual MDL example and it also has the `<i class="material-icons"></i>` code. So the square should be there. My links in `<head>` look like this:

```
<head>
  <title>Store</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the font was missing. I was wrong to assume it is built-in in the .css file of MDL framework.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
```

This line was needed as stated in the Getting Started guide on MDL's site.